# Counting number of times something occurs in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table in SAS with the date, company names and an industry category (1:49).

Is there some simple code which counts how many companies are in each industry in each date.

So the industry category is what I need to count. Count how many times this industry category appears on every date.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Proc freq, you can also use First. and last. concept for this problem.

```
Proc sort data=companies;
by date Industry_category;
run;

Data companies(drop= company_names);
set companies;
by date Industry_category;
If first.Industry_category then count=1;
else count+1;
if last.Industry_category;
run;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

A frequency table lists how many times each distinct combination of variable values occurs in a dataset.  Each combination is also known as a 'bin'.  The number of bins in frequency table might be called the 'cardinality', or the number of distinct values.

There are many ways to produce a frequency table in SAS.

Proc FREQ is a common starting point for simple grouping.

However, the question says

> how many companies are in each industry in each date

so that means get the cardinality count of a sub-level.  SQL can do that in a single query:

```
**** simulate data begin;
data companies;
  do companyId = 1 to 1000;
    industryId = ceil(49*ranuni(123));
    output;
  end;
run;

data have;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  do date = '01-jan-2016'd to '31-dec-2018'd;
    if weekday(date) in (1,7) then continue; * no activity on weekend;
    do _n_ = 1 to 50; * upto 50 random 'events' of random companies;
       if ranuni(123) < 0.60 then continue;
       if ranuni(123) < 0.05 then leave;
       eventId+1;
       point = ceil(1000*ranuni(123));
       set companies point=point;
       output;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
**** simulate data end;

* number of companies within industry (way #1);
* use sub-select to compute the cardinality of company with respect to date/industry;

proc sql;
  create table counts1 (label="Number of companies per date/industry") as
  select 
    date
  , industryId
  , count (distinct companyId) as number_of_companies
  from 
    (
      select date, industryId, companyId, count(*) as number_of_company_events_on_date
      from have
      group by date, industryId, companyId
    )
  group by date, industryId
  ;

* number of companies within industry (way #2);
* use catx to construct the sub-level combination (bins) to be distinctly counted;

 create table counts1B as
 select
   date
 , industryId
 , count (distinct catx(':',industryId,companyId)) as number_of_companies
 group by date, industryId 
 ;

* bonus: just number of industries (ignoring companies);

  create table counts2 (label="Number of industries per date") as
  select 
    date
  , count (distinct industryId) as number_of_industries
  from have
  group by date
  ;

* bonus: disjoint counts of each category (company industry hierarchical relationship ignored);

  create table counts3 (label="Counts for industry and company by date") as
  select 
    date
  , count (distinct industryId) as number_of_industries
  , count (distinct companyId) as number_of_companies
  from have
  group by date
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

PROC FREQ is the easiest way to get that answer.

```
proc freq data=have;
  tables date*industry / list missing;
run;
```

That will be a count of how many times that industry appears on the given date. If there is only one observation per date, industry, company combination then it is also the count of the number of companies in that industry on that date.